# Qt error - probably wrongly used pointer issue

Tags: qt

Can someone help with resolving this error?

```
QString *description = new QString;
description = *dialog.descriptionEdit->toPlainText();
```

error: no match for 'operator*' in '*QTextEdit::toPlainText() const()'

and when I try:

```
QString *description = new QString;
description = dialog.descriptionEdit->toPlainText();
```

error: cannot convert 'QString' to 'QString*' in assignment

Comment: It should be *description = dialog.descriptionEdit->toPlainText();

Comment: However why are you using QString*? I would not use that in most cases.

Comment: you are using pointer on `QString` while is it unnecessary, and using `QDialog` by value when it is highly discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this

```
*description = dialog.descriptionEdit->toPlainText();
```

otherwise you are assigning to the **pointer** not the object it points to. `description` is a pointer to `QString`, `*description` is a `QString`.

Comment: I've suggest to use `QString description;`. There is implicit sharing in Qt, so no need in dynamic QString allocation.

Comment: What if `dialog` is a pointer to a child-class of QDialog and it cannot be just an object as it is passed as an argument to a method?

Comment: The QString will still be a QString (not a QString*) even though you use a pointer to the dialog that has the QString member.